# WordPress header missing

Tags: html, wordpress

I am the webmaster for my high school's student [newspaper website](http://www.theghsjournal.com/), which runs on WordPress. The logo in the header on the site shows up on the main page, but when I click on any of the articles, the logo disappears and the the alt text shows instead. Here is the logo section from the header.php in the theme.

```
<!-- Logo -->
<div class="logo">
<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>"><img id="logo" src="wp-content/uploads/2012/10/5.png" alt="The GHS Journal" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" /></a>
</div>
<!-- /Logo -->
```

Any tips for fixing this problem are well appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using a relative path. You should be using this:

```
<img id="logo" src="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/5.png" alt="The GHS Journal" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
```